# Sending jms message causes warning

Tags: wildfly-10, jms-topic

when sending a message through a JMS topic, I often get the following warning:

```
2016-07-22 14:32:02,418 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client] (Finalizer) AMQ122000: I''m closing a JMS connection you left open. Please make sure you close all JMS connections explicitly before letting them go out of scope! see stacktrace to find out where it was created: java.lang.Exception
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection.<init>(ActiveMQConnection.java:155)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:750)
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createContext(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:255)
at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.create(JMSContextProducer.java:195)
at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.getDelegate(JMSContextProducer.java:235)
at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.createProducer(JMSContextProducer.java:270)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
```

My code:

```
@Inject
@JMSConnectionFactory("java:/ConnectionFactory")
private JMSContext context;

@Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/topic/MyTopic", type = Long.class)
private Topic topic;

public void sendMessage(Event event) {
    try {
        context.createProducer().send(topic, 1L);
    } catch (Exception e) {;
        log.error("Error while sending message to the JMS topic. Will retry later.", e);
    }
}
```

Any idea? I couldn't find anything on google yet.

According to JMSContext javadoc, the connection should be automatically closed when it's managed by the application server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the message clearly explains the problem. Probably you just need to call close() or some sort on the producer you created.

Edit:

Actually, it is not the produced that needs closing, but the context.

From the doc (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSContext.html):

> All these JMSContext objects are application-managed and must be
>   closed when no longer needed by calling their close method.

About the producer, it says (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSProducer.html):

> Instances of JMSProducer are intended to be lightweight objects which
>   can be created freely and which do not consume significant resources.
>   This interface therefore does not provide a close method.

Comment: Hi, I added a call to close, and now he tells me, " It is not permitted to call this method o
n injected JMSContext (see JMS 2.0 spec, º12.4.5)."

Comment: In the Above mentioned javadoc to JMSContext it says _Applications running in the Java EE web and EJB containers may alternatively inject a JMSContext into their application using the @Inject annotation. A JMSContext that is created in this way is described as being container-managed. A container-managed JMSContext will be closed automatically by the container. _ So no I don't need to call close on the context.

Comment: Oh and as an update: If you try to close an injected JMSContext, you get the following exception: javax.jms.IllegalStateRuntimeException: WFLYMSGAMQ0068: It is not permitted to call this method on injected JMSContext (see JMS 2.0 spec, º12.4.5).

Comment: That is intentional/logical: you should only close what you have created. If it is injected, it is created by the DI container and as such the DI container is also responsible for closing it.

Comment: Ok then it looks like a bug in Wildfly or am I wrong?